# Charts aren't rendered in MS Access forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts, ms-access-2003, repaint

I created a form that contains 5 charts. When opening, the cursor changes 5 times, so obviously the data is queried, but the charts aren't rendered and left blank. However, when moving the form outside of the screen and back in, parts of the chart are shown, so it seems that is just a repaint missing.

I tried to execute `me.chart1.repaint` on several events, but I haven't found the appropriate event and I am not sure if `me.chart1.repaint` is actually necessary.

Comment: I had this problem in the past and never found a proper solution, however, I noticed that minimizing the from and then bringing them up again showed the charts.

Comment: @Remou Thanks for your suggestion, I managed to find a solution. Post an answer if you like.

Comment: It hardly qualifies as an answer. Why not answer you own question? It is permitted, and even encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub chart1_Updated(Code as integer)
    me!chart1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Don't worry if visible already true!

Comment: over simplication of the question dont you think?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code as a workaround:

```
 Private Sub chart1_Updated(Code As Integer)
      DoCmd.Minimize
      [Forms]![myform].SetFocus
      DoCmd.Restore
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the form is doing too many things while rendering the graphs, and the actual painting does not have time to finish before processing moves on the next object. You can force Access to "catch a breath" like this:

```
Private Sub Detail_Paint()

    DoEvents

End Sub
```

Since the Detail section of the form is doing the actual rendering, it has a chance to finish each object before moving on to the next.